# Filter query by last 10 entries in a row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write some queries and i want to limit them by the last 50 entries.

```
SELECT  CAST(sum(CASE WHEN US.flg_tip THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS REAL) / 
            (sum(CASE WHEN US.id_entry > 0 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) - sum(CASE WHEN A.action = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
FROM         user AS U, user_statistics AS US, actions AS A
WHERE        US.id_user = U.id_user AND
             AS.id_usertype = 1 AND
             A.id_action = US.id_action AND
             U.id_store = 5 AND
             U.user_name LIKE 'Smith%'
LIMIT 50
```

However LIMIT 50 dose not work in this case.

Please help. Thanks!
note( performance is important because it's expected to work with large databases)

edit:
The formula in the SELECT section that i use to calculate is basically
(number of tips / (number of entries - number of orders)

edit2: The SELECT dose some math function as i explained, and it's working great for Smith (but for all rows for Smith)

If i want to see how Smith behaved in the last 50 visits i imagined i could use LIMIT 50 to get the last 50 entries in my database for Smith and make the query make the math and give me a number how Smith behaved in these last 50 visits with using the LIMIT 50.

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: What are the "last 50" entries? By which field do you want them ordered?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @kchason i am not sure by which field... i need the last 50 entries in the database that were logged. (perhaps by date)

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as "the last row" in a relational database. Rows in a table are **NOT** sorted. Unless you have some column to `order by` you can't define what the "last 50 rows" are

Comment: @masky007, "perhaps by date" doesn't help us help you. Perhaps you have an auto increment field and you want the highest 50 ids. Perhaps there's a timestamp column that you want the greatest 50. Perhaps you want the greatest 50 users by a last logged in field...

Comment: @kchason i see, sorry for my newbishness. i have id_visit (which can be used by that) or date_visited as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *sum* the last 50 entries, you need a subquery:

```
SELECT CAST(sum(CASE WHEN flg_tip THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS REAL) / 
            (sum(CASE WHEN US.id_entry > 0 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) - 
             sum(CASE WHEN A.action = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
           )
FROM (SELECT US.*, A.action
      FROM user U JOIN
           user_statistics US
           ON  US.id_user = U.id_user JOIN
           actions A
           ON A.id_action = US.id_action
       WHERE US.id_usertype = 1 AND
             U.id_store = 5 AND
             U.user_name LIKE 'Smith%'
       ORDER BY . . .
       LIMIT 50
      ) u;
```

Notes:

- I fixed your archaic join syntax.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- If you want the last 50 rows, you need an `ORDER BY`. I don't know which column(s) which is why there is a `. . .`.
- I fixed the an invalid table alias as well.

You can simplify the outer `SELECT` to:

```
SELECT (sum( (flg_tip)::numeric ) / 
        (sum( (US.id_entry > 0)::numeric ) - sum( (A.action = '')::numeric ) )
       )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this Gordon
 I can't test this currently on a large database (however performance will be very important)... by how much this query will be slower (when using subquery and order by, on a large database, let's say 5+ million rows, compared to my original code)
Could you give some insight on this?

Thank you again!

Comment: @masky007 . . . The performance will be dominated by how many rows match the `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: yes but it won't make a difference performance-wise that i have a temporal table "u". at the end? Or that i am using a sub-query and order by?
I mean compared to my original code when i posted my question

Comment: @masky007 . . . Subqueries don't necessarily incur performance overhead.

Comment: Thanks, somewhere i'v read that using subquery is a performance bottleneck, that's why i asked.